# SQL Server connection string ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is my connection string to a remote SQL Server :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebSiteDB"
         connectionString="Server=.MSSQLSERVER2012;Database=mydb;User Id=myid;Password=mypw;"   
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I open my connection it throws an exception :

> Named Pipes Provider, error: 40

Can someone help me?

Comment: When you installed SQL, if you're using Express, it has NO networking allowed. You need to go to SQL Server settings and enable a transport (net pipes or TCP).

Answer (score 1):

The format of the Server attribute is `Server=myServerName\myInstanceName`. So I think that you need a backslash after the dot, i.e. `Server=.\MSSQLSERVER2012`

If that doesn't work, then here are two websites that give you connection string formats 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: Seems like it is better but i have now  this exeption : "SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26"

Comment: Are you connecting to a full version of SQL Server, or Express?

Comment: Full version SQLserver 2012

Comment: The "Host" therm is strange, that's the server right ?

Comment: The host will specify the SQL Server instance. Given that it is on a remote machine, it does seem strange to use a dot in front. Have you tried removing the dot and just specifying the instancename i.e. `Server=MSSQLSERVER2012`?

Comment: It gives me the same exception : "Named Pipes Provider, error: 40"

Comment: To help clarify, is MSSQLSERVER2012 the name of the Windows Server that hosts SQL Server? Also, is this a server that is in your network, or is it in the cloud somewhere?

Comment: That's a data base hosted by my hoster, it is not on my network.

Comment: Can you connect to the server using SQL Server Management Studio? If so, what server name do you enter? That should be the server name to use in your connection string.

Comment: From SQLSMS, it gives me the same exception when i put .MSSQLSERVER2012\mydb as server name,.MSSQLSERVER2012 and .\MSSQLSERVER2012

Comment: Specifying a database name as part of the server string won't work, so don't bother with that option. I don't have any experience with remotely hosted databases, so it might be best to contact your hosting provider to see if they can help out.

Comment: Here's a website that might help troubleshoot your problem https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/

Comment: Ye i saw things like that, it mays be a port problem, i'll check it

Answer (score 0):

I corrected an error like this by restarting sql server services.
Restart  MSSQLSERVER service in data server services.

Sql network interface error :26 is for wrong server name or instance name. mostly instance name

Comment: Still the same exception

Comment: Can you see database engine in you local system by sql server management Stadio?

Comment: Cant connect to the server Manager, it gives me the same exception

Comment: Check these : server name or instance name. Are you sure these are correct?

Comment: If windows firewall is off then create an exception for port 1433  and If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put UDP port 1434 into exception.